# Variance being negative

Tags: probability, distributions, variance, density-function, joint-distribution

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf such that
>
> $$f(x,y) = 3e^{-3x-y}, 0 < x< \infty, 0< y< \infty.$$
>
> (a) Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.
>
> (b) Calculuate $Var(X)$.

In problem $(b)$ I kept getting the result of $-\frac13$. But it is obvious that I should not get the negative variance, right??

You see, the pdf $f(x)$ should be $3e^{-3x}$ and $var(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$

$E(X)=1,$
$\qquad E(X^2)=\frac23$

What's wrong with this??

Comment: Could you show us how you compute those expectations? Clearly at least one of them is wrong, so checking those computations is the next thing you should do.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(x) = \begin{cases} 3\exp(-3x) & x \ge 0 \\ 0 & x < 0\end{cases}$  is the pdf of an exponential distribution.

The corresponding $E[X]= \frac1{\lambda}=\frac13$.

Also, the variance is supposed to be $\frac1{\lambda^2}=\frac19$.

That is  $E[X^2]-\frac19=\frac19$, $E[X^2]= \frac29$. Hence check the computation for the two moments.

It seems that you are missing by a factor of $\frac13$ for both terms.

Answer (score 1):

@Siong Thye Goh provided a great start. This provides a bit more depth and isn't meant to replace the other answer.

You have joint PDF $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 3\text{e}^{-3x-y}$ for $x>0$ and $y>0$.

**(a)** You can recover the marginals [(wiki page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_distribution). 
$$f_X(x) = \int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$$ and
$$f_Y(y) = \int_0^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx$$

You will prove independence if you can show that the joint density is the product of the marginal densities, i.e. $f_X(x)f_Y(y) = f_{X,Y}(x,y)$.

**(b)** I've no doubt you found $f_X(x) = 3\text{e}^{-3x}$ [(WolframAlpha)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5B3+e%5E(-3+x+-+y),%7By,0,inf%7D%5D).
If you recognized this as $X\sim Exponential(\lambda=3)$ like @Siong Thye Goh then you're done as the mean and variance are known formulas using $\lambda$ [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution).

If not, you can recover these from the PDF. 
$$ \text{E}(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty xf_X(x)dx=\int_0^\infty 3x\text{e}^{-3x}dx=\frac{1}{3}\quad \quad \left(\frac{1}{\lambda} \right) $$

We know $\text{Var}(X) = \text{E}[(X-\text{E}[X])^2] = \text{E}[X^2] - \text{E}[X]^2$ and we have $\text{E}[X]$. Using $\text{E}[g(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)f_X(x)dx$, 
$$\text{E}(X^2) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f_X(x)dx=\int_0^\infty 3x^2\text{e}^{-3x}dx=\frac{2}{9}\quad \quad \left(\frac{2}{\lambda^2} \right) $$

Then $\text{Var}(X) = \frac{2}{9} - \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{9}$.